# How to write qsort comparison function for integers?

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

`c` library function qsort takes a comparison function to compare integers. Google search suggests the following

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types 
    const int *ib = (const int *)b;
    return *ia  - *ib; 
}
```

This has the problem of signed integer overflow(or underflow) which is undefined in `c`. The straightforward solution is very verbose and may not be the best.

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types 
    const int *ib = (const int *)b;
    if(*ia > *ib) {
        return 1;
    } else if (*ia == *ib) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Other option is to use wider length signed integers like `long long int`, but the problem still remains when we have to sort `long long int`s.

What is an optimal alternative given that sorting integers is a very common thing to do?

Comment: What is the problem with the solution you have? You might have better luck at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: the answer of chux is probably the best you can do.

Comment: There are many similar questions.  Your second comparator is more correct than the first, precisely because of possible overflow.  You could use `int ia = *(const int *)a; int ib = *(const int *)b;` then compare `ia` and `ib` rather than using pointers throughout, but the compiler probably optimizes it for you anyway.

Comment: No need to cast those `void`-pointers in C.